# Argument value is not getting passed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm passing some value on a `onclick=function('')` function but the value is not getting passed

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo '<a href="#" onclick="DeleteUser('.$id.')"><img class="rmv-img" src="img/bin-with-lid.png"></a>';
}


function DeleteUser(deleteid){
    var conf = confirm("deleteid");
    if (conf == true) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "submit/graduation-submit.php",
            type :'POST',
            data: {  deleteid : deleteid},
        });
    }
}
```

Here in the parameter I should get the value of `id` but on the alert side, this is showing `deleteid` itself

Comment: try this:  `var conf = confirm("do you want to delete"+deleteid);`

Comment: Are you able to get the value as $id under your php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is only the double quotes:

```
var conf = confirm(deleteid);
```

This will show the value of the id in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing argument to your `confirm` box,

```
var conf = confirm("deleteid");
```

Passing `"deleteid"` is nothing but a string and not an argument. If you want to show `deleteid` on confirm box then do this,

```
var conf = confirm("Are you sure, you want to delete "+deleteid);
```